# How to add event tracking to an anchor link click without an Address Bar change

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Our WordPress website is using Divi, which prevents the anchor address being added to the address bar when clicking on anchor links.

How do we use Google Tag Manager to track in Google Analytics clicks on the following link:

```
<a href="#contact" id="contact-insight" target="_self"><img src="..."> Connect</a>
```

**Update**: to avoid screwing things up, we used Google Analytics Dashboard for WordPress by Exact Metrics, and [their tutorial on custom link attribution](https://www.exactmetrics.com/docs/custom-link-attribution/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track it with either a UA tag Event type, using a link click trigger based on the element ID..
or
Same principal but configure a UA Tag Pageview Type, and configure the Fields to Set for the path and page title (which will create and send a virtual pageview), again using a link click trigger based on the element ID

Comment: Which element ID, the link, or the anchor?

Comment: The link ID id="contact-insight"